# Python package to display/interact with keyboard on-screen?

Tags: python, graphics, package

I have data on how frequently certain keys are pressed on the keyboard stored in a dictionary. I want to be able to integrate that data with an on-screen keyboard with different shades to demonstrate the frequency distribution of keys' being pressed. What Python packages or integrations allow this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you'll find a library for displaying keyboard maps graphically as an on-screen keyboard -- specially because keyboard maps usually vary from country to country.

You'll probably need to come up with one yourself.

I'd probably start with an existing [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) image like this:

[image]
Download from: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Qwerty.svg

Check the SVG source code, try inspecting it in the browser to see how each keys are mapped -- once you have a map from the keys to the SVG objects, you can render it painting each key in a different color according to the frequency.

#### Learn more about SVG:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial

Comment: I'm just looking to use a standard, U.S. keyboard (one you'd expect to find here). The keyboard only deals with `ascii_lowercase`, so 26 chars.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this can be done by firstly; creating a keyboard with Tkinter then depending on the frequency that the letters are in, define the shade of the button or box the letters are individually displayed as. For example if you set borderlines for say between; green, yellow, and red as, pressed between 1-10 then 10-20 etc.. you could then change the colour of the button/box displayed on the Tkinter-made keyboard to show the frequency distribution. I am unsure whether there is currently a package available to do this easier.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. So, Tkinter is the package to get me started?

Comment: I would say that without doing extensive research into finding another package. What I would do is use Tkinter to create the window and on-screen keyboard etc, then shade the individual keys based on the letter's frequency. Online somewhere there may already be an on-screen keyboard template for the Tkinter module.